# Can I get data from ros to a file?

Tags: ros, data

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 and ros hydro,

I'm curently playing around with an ar drone with the tum_ardrone package. I wanted to know if theres a way to output data to a text file? I know I can use rostopic echo to get the data published to a terminal, but is there a way to get it somewere else?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/190333/can-i-get-data-from-ros-to-a-file?/) by [dshimano](https://answers.ros.org/users/19862/dshimano/) on ROS Answers with karma: 129 on 2014-08-15

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I dont want to steal @bvbdort thunder, but I think you should probably save to a .bag file first and then change to a .txt or .csv file. Going directly to a text file, particularly if you are working with any imaging output from the bot can get weird quickly.

I believe the "ROS" way to do this would be to run a command like

```
    $rosbag record <topic>
```

And then move it over to a .txt/.csv file. A useful script to do this can be found here:
( http://answers.ros.org/question/9102/how-to-extract-data-from-bag/?answer=63877#post-id-63877 )
which converts to a .csv. This will save the data long-term and allow a cleaner transition in the short term.

---

Originally posted by [jc2016](https://answers.ros.org/users/19388/jc2016/) with karma: 150 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To save data from ros topic to text file. It saves a `.txt` file in current directory,

```
rostopic echo /scan >>mydata.txt
```

Have looking into [rosbag](http://wiki.ros.org/rosbag) to save data and play it later.

---

Originally posted by [bvbdort](https://answers.ros.org/users/9486/bvbdort/) with karma: 3034 on 2014-08-15

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [emacsd](https://answers.ros.org/users/3662/emacsd/) on 2014-08-18**:
That's nice! I never thought about this idea!